# Why does Format Whole Document in Visual Studio 2019 add new lines in SVG code?

Tags: visual-studio, svg, code-formatting

I have an ASP.Net Core webpage I'm editing in Visual Studio 2019. It's actually the _layout.cshtml page.
I'm pasting SVG code inline in the html after I've edited it in a different application.

When I paste the SVG code in my span control, it looks something like this...

```
<span>
    <svg svg details here...>
        <path d="coordinates here..."/>
        <path d="coordinates here..."/>
        <path d="coordinates here..."/>
    </svg>
</span>
```

However, when I click the "Format the Whole Document" button on the tool bar in Visual Studio (or press CTRL - E, D) I get new lines in my SVG code every time (only in the SVG code - not the rest of my document).

This means if I press it once, I get

```
<span>
    <svg svg details here...>

        <path d="coordinates here..."/>

        <path d="coordinates here..."/>

        <path d="coordinates here..."/>

    </svg>
</span>
```

and if I press it again, I'll have this...

```
<span>
    <svg svg details here...>


        <path d="coordinates here..."/>


        <path d="coordinates here..."/>


        <path d="coordinates here..."/>


    </svg>
</span>
```

After adding an SVG that had about 100 lines in it, and trying multiple times to format my document, my page was looking rather sparse!

Does anyone know why this is happening, and how to stop it?

Comment: presumably its a bug you should report to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. This article helped me: [Working with SVG files in Visual Studio and Visual Web Developer](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/working-with-svg-files-in-visual-studio-and-visual-web-developer/). As a result, my code was slightly different than the closing tag:

> ```
> <object data="~/Content/svg/next.svg" type="image/svg+xml"></object>
> ```